# PrimeFaces timeline component not working on IE8

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces, internet-explorer-8, timeline

I'm using a timeline component (pe:timeline) in a project and it works fine on Chrome, but not on IE8.

The problem I'm stuck on is that on IE8 the component is not rendered at all.
The code I'm using:

Javascript:

```
function showContent() {  
    $('#textArea').val(PF('timelineWdgt').getSelectedEvent().content);  
}
```

xhtml:

```
<h:body>
     <f:event id="postConstructorEvent"
        type="javax.faces.event.PreRenderComponentEvent"
        listener="#{acervoBean.inicializaPaginaAcervo}" />
     <p:growl id="growl" showSummary="true" showDetail="true" autoUpdate="true"/> 
     <h:form id="searchMultimidia">
        <h:panelGroup class="nav">
           <h:panelGrid columns="2" class="grid" style="width:90%">
        <pe:timeline id="timeline" locale="pt_BR" value="#{acervoBean.model}"  
                     editable="true" showButtonNew="false"
                     showNavigation="true" zoomMin="1500000000"
                     timeZone="#{acervoBean.timeZone}"  
                     widgetVar="timelineWdgt" style="margin-top:10px;">  
            <pe:javascript event="select" execute="showContent()"/>  
            <p:ajax event="delete" update="@none" onstart="timelineWdgt.cancelDelete()"/>
            <p:ajax event="add" update="@none" onstart="timelineWdgt.cancelAdd()"/>
        </pe:timeline>  
...
...
```

Bean:

```
@PostConstruct
public void postContruct() {
    model = new TimelineModel();

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    model.add(new TimelineEvent("Dia inicial", cal.getTime()));

    cal.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH, 1);
    model.add(new TimelineEvent("Dia final", cal.getTime()));
}
...
...
```

I'm using 
Mojarra 2.1.17 ,
Primefaces 3.5 and
Apache Tomcat 7.0.56

Thanks.

Comment: Check if IE is running in compatibility mode…  it should not be

Comment: I've checked that. It's not running in compatibility mode. @Kukeltje

Comment: Do you have JS errors? As far as I remember, pe:timeline has a problem that it calls `console.log` even though IE doesn't have it defined if you don't open the developer tools.